# Government gmail on personal phone

Tags: gmail, privacy

I have personal iphone that i check government email on via gmail app.  Unbeknownst to me, my google app became associated with my work account.  I did some google searches that I do NOT want my employer to know about.  Will that history be visible to them? I looked at "Manage Activity History" and there was a message that says "Based on your organization's current settings, this feature is disabled. If your administrator changes this in the future, your choice will be honored" Does that mean they are tracking history or does that mean that they haven't enabled it?